# Highlight ListBox items based on value from class

Tags: c#, winforms, loops, class, listbox

Is it possible to loop through items in a ListBox and highlight or indicate item unavailability somehow by checking a class for a value?

Basically, got a Game class and within stored info whether Game is Available so I need to check this class when looping through the ListBox Items and somehow indicate on the ListBox if GameAvailable = false.

Got to this point and not sure how to carry on:

```
private void HighlightUnavailable()
    {
        foreach(string item in listbox_consoles.Items)
        {
            foreach (Products.Game game in GameService.AllGames())
            {
                if (item == game.GameName.ToString())
                {
                    if (game.GameAvailable)
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not *remove* unwanted items (with `GameAvailable == false`)?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko its for a Form where users can display all available Games but need indication on the list which products are available.

Comment: What is this? WinForms, WPF, ..etc?

Comment: @JQSOFT apologies, I should of mentioned that initially - it is WinForms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that's possible in such a way as:

- Bind the ListBox to the `GameService.AllGames()` which returns I believe a list or an array of the `Game` objects.
- Set the [ListBox.DrawMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.drawmode?view=netcore-3.1) to `DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed` and handle the [ListBox.DrawItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.drawitem?view=netcore-3.1) event to draw the items according to their `GameAvailable` properties.

Assuming the controls names are `Form1` and `listBox1`, add in `Form1` constructor:

```cs
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    //...

    listBox1.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
    listBox1.DrawItem += (s, e) => OnListBoxDrawItem(s, e); 
    listBox1.DataSource = GameService.AllGames();
}
```

Say you want to display the available games with green and the rest with red foreground colors.

```cs
private void OnListBoxDrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    //Comment if you don't need to show the selected item(s)...
    e.DrawBackground();

    if (e.Index == -1) return;

    var game = listBox1.Items[e.Index] as Game;
    var foreColor = game.GameAvailable ? Color.Green : Color.Red;

    //Pass the listBox1.BackColor instead of the e.BackColor 
    //if you don't need to show the selection...
    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, game.GameName, e.Font,
        e.Bounds, foreColor, e.BackColor,
        TextFormatFlags.Left | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter);
}
```

... or with different background colors:

```cs
private void OnListBoxDrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Index == -1) return;

    var game = listBox1.Items[e.Index] as Game;          

    var backColor = e.State.HasFlag(DrawItemState.Selected)
        ? e.BackColor
        : game.GameAvailable
        ? Color.LightGreen
        : listBox1.BackColor;

    //Or this if you don't need to show the selection ...
    //var backColor = game.GameAvailable
    //  ? Color.LightGreen
    //  : listBox1.BackColor;

    using (var br = new SolidBrush(backColor))
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, e.Bounds);

    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, game.GameName, e.Font,
        e.Bounds, Color.Black, backColor,
        TextFormatFlags.Left | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter);
}
```

... or with a couple of yes [image: Yes] and no [image: No] images from your resources:

```cs
Bitmap YesImage, NoImage;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    //...

    YesImage = Properties.Resources.YesImage;
    NoImage = Properties.Resources.NoImage;

    listBox1.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
    listBox1.DrawItem += (s, e) => OnListBoxDrawItem(s, e);
    listBox1.DataSource = GameService.AllGames();
    this.FormClosed += (s, e) => { YesImage.Dispose(); NoImage.Dispose(); };
}

private void OnListBoxDrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Index == -1) return;

    var game = listBox1.Items[e.Index] as Game;
    var backColor = e.State.HasFlag(DrawItemState.Selected)
        ? e.BackColor
        : listBox1.BackColor;
    var bmp = game.GameAvailable ? YesImage : NoImage;
    var rectImage = new Rectangle(
        3, e.Bounds.Y + ((e.Bounds.Height - bmp.Height) / 2),
        bmp.Width, bmp.Height
        );
    var rectTxt = new Rectangle(
        rectImage.Right + 3, e.Bounds.Y,
        e.Bounds.Right - rectImage.Right - 3,
        e.Bounds.Height
        );

    using (var br = new SolidBrush(backColor))
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, e.Bounds);

    e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, rectImage);

    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, game.GameName, e.Font,
            rectTxt, Color.Black, backColor,
            TextFormatFlags.Left | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter);
}
```

[image: SOQ61607771]

Comment: Thank you, this works great! Went with the yes/no images and I think that looks best.

Comment: May I ask where you got the red & green icons from? Ones I've got don't look as good as the ones on your preview. Thanks!

Comment: @Pawel Here buddy https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xzh8t.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZqUz.png