# Highlight specific items in listbox based on their status in database

Tags: c#, .net

I have a table in a database with ID, name and gender columns. I populate the listbox like this:

```
    public void fill_listbox()    
    {
        lbProjects.Items.Clear();
        con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT name FROM Table1", con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            lbProjects.Items.Add(dr["name"].ToString());
        }
        con.Close();
    }
```

Is it possible to highlight (not select) all the items that have specific gender in the listbox?
For example change the background color/font-weight/font color for all items that have "male" as gender in the database.

[image: To look something like this]

If it is not possible using the listbox, what another component I can use?

Comment: You can use the same approach [Highlight ListBox items based on value from class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61649395/10216583)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by using listview instead.

```
public void fill_listbox()
    {
        listView1.Columns.Add("", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left); 
        listView1.Items.Clear();
        con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT name,gender FROM Table1", con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();

            if (dr["gender"].ToString() == "male")
            {
                lvi.Text = dr["name"].ToString();
                lvi.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
                listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
            }
            else {
                lvi.Text = dr["name"].ToString();
                lvi.ForeColor = Color.Pink;
                listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
            }
        }
        con.Close();

    }
```